# Set generated Texture2D on terrain in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a simple Texture2D in Unity as follows (simplified example):

```
   Texture2D texture2d = new Texture2D(256,256);
   for (int h = 0; h < texture2d.height; h++) {
        for (int w = 0; w < texture2d.width ; w++) {
            texture2d.SetPixel(w,h, Color.green);
        }
    }
```

How can I set this created Texture2D at a existing terrain, as ground texture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the built-in `Terrain` shaders don't have a `_MainTexture` property, you have to use a custom one: e.g. http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/TerrainFourLayerToon (place in a `.shader` file)

from there you just need the appropriate code

```
//your code here
texture2d.Apply(); //missing in your code!

Material mat = new Material(Shader.Find("Terrain/Four Layer Toon Compat")); //from link
mat.SetTexture("_MainTex" , texture2d); //set the texture properties of the shader
mat.SetTexture("_MainTex2", texture2d);
mat.SetTexture("_MainTex3", texture2d);
mat.SetTexture("_MainTex4", texture2d);

Terrain terr = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Terrain>(); //get the terrain
terr.materialType = Terrain.MaterialType.Custom; //tell the terrain you want to manually assign its material
terr.materialTemplate = mat; //finally assign the material (and texture)
```

this code should work in Unity 5

If you are curious what any of these functions do, check https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Reference.html for `ShaderLab`, `CG`, and the `.shader` filetype

and http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ under `UnityEngine` -> `Classes` for `GameObject`, `Material`, `Shader`, `Terrain`, and `Texture2D`.